# Undefined error when using Javascript array outputted by PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Why is it that Chrome console still gives me an **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Users' of undefined** but the script works fine?

I'm using PHP to generate values into a javascript array inline to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

dbArray = [

<?php
if (!$connect) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("myMysqlTable", $connect);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nhoods");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : 
?>
{ "Name":"<?php echo $row['Name'] ?>", "Users":<?php echo $row['Users'] ?> },
<?php endwhile; mysql_close($connect); ?>

];

</script>
```

Here is an example of output:

```
var dbArray = [
    { "Name":"Outer Richmond", "Users":5 },
    { "Name":"Central Richmond", "Users":3 },
    { "Name":"Inner Richmond", "Users":12 },
    { "Name":"USF NoPa", "Users":2 }
    ];
```

In a separate .js file I have the following example:

```
function someFunction(index) { 
    var usersfound = dbArray[index]['Users'];
        console.log(usersfound);
};

someFunction(2);
```

The users return perfectly fine and this works, but it still throws the error.

I understand that php loads server-side but why does it seem like my javascript file doesn't exist in the same realm as the inline page javascript.

Comment: Check the order of your script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the cause, the error was occurring because the PHP row output was not complete therefore my script would error anytime it tried to pull something from the list that did not exist.  The script checks out now. I'll probably put a conditional around the reference to make sure the value exists first.

ie:

```
    var users
    if (dbArray[index]['Users']) {
       users = dbArray[index]['Users'];
    }
```